# Can I have multiple ssh on the same machine?

Tags: ssh, docker

I have some domain (ie domain1.info and domain2.info) and are both pointing to my machine1.
On that machine1 I want to have an ssh server that listens on domain1.info:22 and a docker container (in particular an instance of Omnibus-GitLab) with some services running on subdomain.domain2.info, including ssh on port 22. Is that even possible?

I have only one public IP address.

The machine1 is running Arch Linux, openSSH, docker and nginx.

I'm starting to learn just now so I'm little bit a noob so if you know some userfull guide/resource I will appreciate a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I have multiple ssh on the same machine?

Yes, so long as they're on different IP addresses or different ports.

Comment: first of all thank you! so I can have openSSH on port xxxx and the container on yyyy, but is it possible to have domain1.info:22 and subdomain.domain2.info:22 on the same machine (with only one public ip) and turn the traffic to the two different location based on the url requested?